# Exception throws bad request 400

Tags: c#, onedrive

Please provide me some idea for a solution for this error-message:

> Exception throws bad request 400

Code:

```
public static T MakeRequestPost<T>(string requestUrl)
{
    try
    {
        string postContent = requestUrl.Substring(requestUrl.IndexOf('?') + 1);
        string url = requestUrl.Substring(0, requestUrl.IndexOf('?'));

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = postContent.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(postContent, 0, postContent.Length);
        }

        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception(String.Format(
                   "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription));

            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
            T jsonResponse = (T)objResponse;
            return jsonResponse;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return default(T);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the request url?

Comment: Bad request is a very broad error. It's impossible for us to answer your question without knowing the content that you are sending and what parameters the service expects to get.

Comment: https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf?client_id=00000000BB8&redirect_uri=https://oauth.live.com/desktop&client_secret=lyb40v2efsO3oE8oRbjN1kveanlv&code=7a4359d-327-cb4b-5877-6675d31b63&grant_type=authorization_code